# export gridview data to pdf

Tags: c#, asp.net

its throwing error like document has no pages.

i have written code like this.

```
protected void Button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition","attachment;filename=GridViewExport.pdf");
    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
    GridView1.AllowPaging = false;
    GridView1.DataBind();
    GridView1.RenderControl(hw);
    StringReader sr = new StringReader(sw.ToString());
    Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 10f, 10f, 10f, 0f);
    HTMLWorker htmlparser = new HTMLWorker(pdfDoc);
    PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, Response.OutputStream);
    pdfDoc.Open();
    htmlparser.Parse(sr);
    pdfDoc.Close();
    Response.Write(pdfDoc);
    Response.End();  
}
```

can any1 help me on this

Comment: What PDF library are you using?

Comment: im using adobe reader9..

Answer (score 1):

I suggest reading the documentation of the library you are using.

The error suggests that you need to add a page to the new document before you try and add content to it.

In some of the PDF libraries you add a page and then need to set it as the current page before adding content.

Comment: @Sweety - As I said. Read the documentation.

Comment: @Sweety - You are using an Adobe reader 9 component. Read the documentation for it.

Comment: @oded-What is the location from where i can download latest itextsharp.dll so that i can use iTextSharp.text.Table type. 

Currently i am having itextsharp-5.0.2-dll 

While using iTextSharp.text.Table, i get error "Type of namespace Table does not exist". 

Even i am not able to use pdftable type.

Comment: @Sweety - So you are _not_ using Adobe for creating the PDF, but iTextSharp. I believe getting it from the iTextSharp site is your best bet.

Comment: @oded-but its throwing error like this "Type of namespace Table does not exist". i have modified the code bit